# I can't write a orc file with spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, orc

I'm trying to write a dataframe to an orc, but to no avail. I'm using Spark 1.6 with Java.
I am running on my local machine, I tried to install some dependencies but without success.

My POM is this:

```
<properties>
        <spark.version>1.6.0</spark.version>
        <scala.short.version>2.10</scala.short.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest_${scala.short.version} -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-avro_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
            <artifactId>play-json_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>




        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0-M4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-parser-combinators</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0-M4</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
```

I have a job spark that I want to write to an orc file, but this error returns me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: orc. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)
    at Confiaveis.main(Confiaveis.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: orc.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
    ... 4 more
```

I used this command to write:

```
df.write().mode("append").format("orc").save("path");
```

does anyone know how i can solve this?
As little as I know of spark, I understand that it's a library he doesn't find, but I can't find anywhere to clarify what that library would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_*your_version*</artifactId>
    <version>*your_version*</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @GabrielSampaio apologies, orc is a hive format, you need that in your dependencies. See edit

Comment: Work!  but now I have another problem: "The ORC data source can only be used with HiveContext."